# How can I call a mutating method while holding a reference to self?

Tags: rust

I'm having a hard time with the borrow checker.

```
for item in self.xxx.iter() {
    self.modify_self_but_not_xxx(item);
}
```

The above code worked *before* I refactored some code into `modify_self_but_not_xxx()`:

```
error: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because `self.xxx` is also borrowed as immutable
```

How can I call a mutating method while holding a reference to `self` (e.g. from within a `for`-loop)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How can I call a mutating method while holding a reference to `self` (e.g. from within a `for`-loop)?

You can't, that's exactly what the borrowing rules prevent.

The main idea is that in your code, the borrow checker cannot possibly know that `self.modify_self_but_not_xxx(..)` will not modify `xxx`.

However, you can mutate `self.yyy` or any other parameters, so either you can:

- do the computations of `modify_self_but_not_xxx(..)` directly in your loop body
- define a helper function taking mutable references to update them:

  ```
  fn do_computations(item: Foo, a: &mut Bar, b: &mut Baz) { /* ... */ }

  /* ... */

  for item in self.xxx.iter() {
      do_computations(item, &mut self.bar, &mut self.baz);
  }
  ```
- define a helper struct that has helper methods

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. **Lesson learned:** when designing functions avoid references to `self` if possible -- don't borrow more than what is minimally necessary.

Comment: There is distinction between method and function in Rust. [The Book ch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html). In short method has reference to Self, while function is simply associated with a struct.